# What are the drawbacks of having a super-long CSS file?

Tags: css

When I started working on my project I didn't really care so much about organizing my CSS file, but then I kept on adding ad-hoc selectors. Now I have 3048 lines of CSS code. I know I need to spend some time organizing this stuff and I know it will be much shorter once I do that since there's really a lot of redundancy.

But currently it's working fine (as it seems at least), and I just want to get the product out the door as soon as possible, so I was wondering, is this OK to have a long CSS like this and what are some of the critical drawbacks if any?

Comment: It takes a super-long time to download.  It takes a super-long time to maintain.  etc.

Comment: The main drawback of the performance is the first-load experience by a user that never visited your site. If it's a public website that sells something, every little thing helps conversion.

Comment: How many bytes is it? On a site I've just finished the CSS was 26kB. I don't consider that too big.

Comment: Just checked and it's 58KB :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3048 lines isn't that bad, but it could be reduced; I'll give you benefit of the doubt and assume that you have a fairly complex site.

Super long CSS files start encountering problems in IE, which can only take a certain number of rules before it starts ignoring the rest.

Also, the longer the file, the more time it takes to parse - thus the longer it takes for your webpage to load.

Of course, with more rules comes more memory usage too.

That's about it, really.

Comment: does a browser parse CSS while downloading file or downloads a file then parse it?

Comment: Thanks, "3048 lines isn't that bad" was the type of answer I wanted to hear :)  I started building this site while learning to code rails, so there's too much code that I would write differently now. (For example, now I know stuff like Sass and would definitely use this if I started over) But the project has become somewhat of a monster and I can't really spend time optimizing this and not release, so probably will just release it and then slowly optimize..

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: It depends on the browser, but for best performance, load the CSS file first so that the browser knows how to render your document without repainting the screen too much.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if you don't mind gaining a reputation for being sloppy. That alone ought to be considered a "critical drawback". It takes no time at all to run it through a minimizer if you're sure that what you have currently is working.

As above, anybody looking at your website thinking about offering you a design opportunity might decide that you're sloppy and not make the offer.

It might take a few milliseconds longer for the client to parse.

It'll take half a second longer to load for people stuck on 768k DSL lines (there are still lots of those around).

Answer (score 0):

- Readability and the subsequent negatives.
- Size. I mean since it is sent to the user, the longer it is the more time it will need (ofc with modern connection this is not a huge issue).

Consider Css language supersets like [LessCss](http://lesscss.org/). It will dramatically decrease the complexity and increase productivity.

Also [minifiers](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/) will help decreasing the size, with the trade off on readability, so minify only what is sent and not the code you are working on.